# How to implement a custom json validator

Tags: json, go

I need to test my system with lots of scenarios. For each scenario I will define the request and expected response, then I will make the request and compare the returned response and expected response.

For example, the REST API /add return a+b.

request:

```
{
    "a":1,
    "b":2
}
```

expected response (validator style description, could be something else since I don't know if there is any better solution):

```
{
    "err_code":"int, required, eq=0"
    "data":"int, required, eq=3"
}
```

returned response:

```
success
{
    "err_code":0,
    "data":3
}

failure
{
    "err_code":500,
    "data":0
}
```

So my question here is, how to implement a custom json validator with some struct/fied/type/value description, or is there any better solution?

[go-playground/validator](https://github.com/go-playground/validator) needs to define everything at struct level, what I need is to check if a json conforms to my descriptive json (something as above).

Comment: What does "kind of descriptive json" mean? What _exactly_ do you need to validate?

Comment: a struct and its'attributes description, specifying its field type, if it is required, value range ...

Comment: It's hard to provide a sensible answer. If you're looking for some "kinda standardized" solution, try https://json-schema.org/ and [3rd party Go packages implementing that](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-go) (stdlib does not have support for that). Otherwise the answer would be a bit glib: 1) sit down; 2) design an approach to implement your custom validator; 4) implement it. Obviously, properly answering 2-4 is not fit for the SO format, and actually that'd be a lot of work. Unpaid work, you see.

Comment: If you actually have some (however vague) idea about how you'd go about implementing your custom validator but have _concrete and narrow_ questions about _some specifics_ of that—then feel free to ask separate, narrow, questions.

Comment: @seaguest are you looking for something like this https://github.com/go-playground/validator? which validates structs, or are you actually looking to validate raw json?

Comment: @kostix thanks for your reply, actually I used go-playground/validator which used reflect for the validation, I think that would be useful. I will see if I can reuse some code of it.

Comment: @mkopriva not exactly, I need to check if a json conforms my descriptive json, but I think it could quite useful to achieve my goal.

Comment: @seaguest I see... in that case kostix is right.

Comment: @kostix finally I used regular expression to implement my simple json validator,here is my repo https://github.com/seaguest/jsonvalidator

Comment: @mkopriva finally I used regular expression to implement my simple json validator,here is my repo https://github.com/seaguest/jsonvalidator

Comment: I can't resist remembering that famous quote of Jamie Zawinski: «Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.» :-)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used regular expression to implement my simple json validator,here is my repo https://github.com/seaguest/jsonvalidator

Still a lot of things need to be done, but it does meet my needs right now.